# Selenium IDE Click on a button in a row identified by text

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to get my script to click on a button called Enter Response located in the same row as a specific text (SID). I am able to locate both separately but can't seem to make both work at the same time.

The table is dynamic so I am using the SID, finding it's row and then want to click on it's response button. I.E. find text '123456' & click on 'Enter Response' found in the same row.

I tried this but am getting an error locator not found:
//tr/td/a[@class='title-abbr' and text()='123456']/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Enter Response']

Table Row Headers:
Title/Source/Source ID/SID/Create Date/(Enter Response button)/Form Type

```
<tr>
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="TITLE_ABBR">this is my title</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="SOURCE_NAME">source1</td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="SOURCE_NUMBER">142417</td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(13, 13, 13);" class="t-Report-cell" headers="SID_ABBR">
       <a href="javascript: void(0);" title="123456" class="title-abbr" style="text-decoration: none;    background-color: transparent;">123456</a>
    </td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="TRANSACTION_DATE">07/28/2016</td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(13, 13, 13);" class="t-Report-cell" headers="LINK" align="center">
       <a style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);" class="response-btn"    href="f?p=58117:50:27077013481519::NO::P50_TRIGGER_ID:321860">Enter Response</a>
    </td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="FORM_TYPE">Questions</td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am looking right, you should first get to the parent node before trying to get to the next sibling....because "a" element has no sibling, so basically something like that:

//tr/td/a[@class='title-abbr' and text()='123456']/../following-sibling::td/a[text()='Enter Response']

You could also just use following-sibling::td[2] instead of selecting by text in the second part of xpath, but maybe you need it for some reason.

Btw some tips:

- If the element could have multiple style classes, you will have to use contains
- The same applies to text, beware of spaces etc. you should trim the text or use contains to avoid wrong selectors

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked beautifully :) and thank you for the explanation and tips as well. It makes so much more sense now!